# Propositional Logic - Is my answer correct?

Tags: logic

I have a question relating to Propositional Logic. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Without changing the meaning of the following formulæ, which
rely on operator precedence to be interpreted correctly, introduce
brackets in each so that no precedence information is required.

(a) $\lnot p \land q \implies r \land p \land q \land \lnot r \iff F$

Ans $((¬p ∧ q) ⇒ (r ∧p )∧(q ∧¬r ))⇔ F$

(b) $¬p ∧ q ∧ r ⇔ ¬p ∨ ¬q ∧¬r$

Ans $(¬p ∧ (q ∧ r)) ⇔ ¬p ∨ (¬q ∧¬r)$

Please can somebody advise me if my answer is correct or incorrect. Thank you all geniuses so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. The missing parens are inserted & highlighted:

(a) $((\lnot p \land q) \rightarrow \color{red}{\bf(}(r \land p) \land (q \land \lnot r)\color{red}{\bf)}) \leftrightarrow F$

(b) $(\lnot p \land (q \land r)) \leftrightarrow \color{red}{\bf(}\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \land \lnot r)\color{red}{\bf)}$

But since they want *no* precedence information assumed, we have to make the formulas uglier:

(a) $((\color{red}{\bf(}\lnot p\color{red}{\bf)} \land q) \rightarrow ((r \land p) \land (q \land \color{red}{\bf(}\lnot r\color{red}{\bf)}))) \leftrightarrow F$

(b) $(\color{red}{\bf(}\lnot p\color{red}{\bf)} \land (q \land r)) \leftrightarrow (\color{red}{\bf(}\lnot p\color{red}{\bf)} \lor (\color{red}{\bf(}\lnot q\color{red}{\bf)} \land \color{red}{\bf(}\lnot r\color{red}{\bf)}))$

Comment: I don’t think that (a) is quite right: surely the expression between the red parentheses ought to be $$\big((r\land p)\land q\big)\land(\neg r)\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That would be more canonical, but this does meet the requirements of "no operator precedence information required" and "without changing the meaning."

Comment: @Trevor: Not quite: it still requires parentheses around $\neg r$.

Comment: @Brian Oh, good point.  I didn't notice that part.

Comment: @Trevor: I’m guilty too: I didn’t notice until just now that the same applies elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't expect so many brackets, but it makes sense!! Thank you guys! God Bless.